# Installing and using third party gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I found a gem and I want to try it. The procedure of gem connecting is described [here](https://habr.com/post/120188/) (in Russian language).

In which file should I write this code, and how can I use this variable in the view?

```
require 'builder'
    xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(target: STDOUT, indent: 2)
    xml.person(type: "programmer") do
    xml.name do
      xml.first "Dave"
      xml.last "Thomas"
    end
 xml.location "Texas"
 xml.preference("ruby")
end
```

Comment: https://richonrails.com/articles/outputting-xml-using-ruby-on-rails

Comment: You can just run this code by pasting it into `irb` or the `rails console`.

Comment: Thanks, guys! I think this is exactly what I need. :)